# How to use c++ boost mapped matrix for e.g. 3D, 4D?

Tags: c++, boost, matrix, 3d, sparse-matrix

I have got question connected with sparse matrix in C++ boost library.

There is something like "boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_sparse.hpp" and there are 3 kind of sparse matrixes.

I wondering if e.g. `mapped_matrix` allow to use it for more than only 2D (two dimensional), but also for 3D, 4D etc.

From documentation I can read that `mapped_matrix<T, F, A>`,

- `T` - The type of object stored in the mapped matrix,
- `F` - Functor describing the storage organization,
- `A` - The type of the adapted array.

So I think that there is maybe possibility to use this mapped matrix for e.g. 3D.

Could you tell me where I can find some example code for e.g. 3D, 4D -> how to use it?

I modified example code from documentation to use `map_std`:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_sparse.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

int main () {
    using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
    mapped_matrix<double, row_major, map_std<std::size_t, double>> m (3, 3, 3 * 3);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < m.size1 (); ++ i)
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < m.size2 (); ++ j)
            m (i, j) = 3 * i + j;
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

But it is still for 2D and I don't know how to use it for e.g. 3D (if there is such possibility)?

Comment: No, it seems to be 2D only (http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Initializing-a-3D-matrix-td4667430.html). However, in your example you initialise all matrix points: in that case, you don't need a sparse matrix, do you?